# Creating constraint against another table with non-unique column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints, primary-key, unique-constraint

I have two SQL Server tables named `Categories` and `CategoryAuthorizations`. I want to ensure all `CategoryAuthorizations.CategoryId` values are in `Categories.CategoryId`. The `Id` column in both tables are `Primary Keys`. The `CategoryId` column in both tables are `non-unique`. Therefore, I cannot use foreign key constraint to ensure referential integrity on `CategoryId`.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Categories](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Category] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Updates] [smallint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Categories] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [Id] ASC
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CategoryAuthorizations](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AuthCode] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Updates] [smallint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CategoryAuthorizations] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [Id] ASC
)
```

Example:

**Table: Categories**

| Id | CategoryId | Category | Status | Updates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Tire | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | Tire | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | Tires | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | Brakes | 1 | 0 |

**Table: CategoryAuthorizations**

| Id | CategoryId | AuthCode | Status | Updates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | SAM | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | CHR | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | SAM | 1 | 0 |

The last record in `CategoryAuthorizations`, where `CategoryAuthorizations.CategoryId = 3`, should never be allowed to be inserted if a constraint is applied because `Category.CategoryId` does not contain a value of 3.

To sum up: How can I *effectively* apply referential integrity on a non-unique column from another table? Is there a constraint or another database solution which can help meet this criteria?

Comment: IMO it seems something has gone astray with your approach. Perhaps it is based on your idea that every table must have an identity column and that column must be the primary key. But let's start by actually defining what CategoryID means / represents in your Categories table. The short answer to your question is - not possible using a constraint. You might consider a trigger but I suggest you revisit the decisions that have brought you to this issue.

Comment: Well, that's a fair comment. My paradigm functions on the use of an Update field, which is a common database design and effectively functions as an audit trail without a separate audit table. If I didn't have an Update field, I could make CategoryId the primary key. Id is the unique record and the CategoryId is the integer value of the Category. As such, CategoryId does not uniquely identify the record. For that, you need Id or CategoryId and the Update field. My design choice was to incorporate Update field and not create separate audit table and I do prefer that approach.

Comment: A trigger seems like a good option. Hmm. Perhaps creating a constraint leveraging a scalar function might be worth a try?

Comment: A separate table would be the correct way to go: you can use CDC and  `SYSTEM_VERSIONING` to automatically store the history. Fundamentally your current database design is wrong: you are storing the same data twice, namely the `CategoryId`. There needs to be a canonical place where all `CategoryId` are stored. If your database is not properly normalized then you will get yourself in knots trying to enforce integrity

Comment: @Charlieface I'll investigate `Change Data Capture (CDC)` and `System_Versioning`, as its currently not enabled on the DB. I'm not sure what are the DB performance drawbacks, including for objects (i.e. tables, views) not utilizing CDC and versioning (ex: eat more memory). On the ServiceNow platform, for example, they use an Updates field and a Sys Id field in the same table and I do think it's a good design. For using this so-called `CategoryId`, yes, my design breaks normalization. I'll have to reconsider my design.

Comment: For what it's doing, CDC is very efficient. It does need some management/monitoring regarding cleanup: the cleanup process can get stuck sometimes